# Net::ftp getbinaryfile() saving to file vs saving to variable

Tags: ruby, default-parameters, net-ftp

Using the following `ftp_download` method works, but if I change

```
ftp.getbinaryfile(file,localdir,1024)   #=> Saves the file to localdir
```

to

```
ftp.getbinaryfile(file)    #=> returns nil
```

I get `nil` returned.  According to

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-getbinaryfile

inilf I set `localfile` to `nil` as above, the data should be retrieved and returned by the method.  What am I doing wrong?

```
def ftp_download(domain,remotedir,filename_regex,user=nil,pwd=nil)
  ftp = Net::FTP::new(domain)
  if user && pwd
    ftp.login(user, pwd)
  end
  ftp.chdir(remotedir)
  fileList = ftp.nlst(filename_regex)

  fileList.each do |file|
    localdir=File.join(remotedir,file)
    localdir=localdir[1..-1] if localdir[0]="/"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(localdir))
    ftp.getbinaryfile(file,localdir,1024)
  end
  ftp.close
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the `getbinaryfile` method signature you will notice that the default value for the second parameter (`localfile`) is not `nil` but `File.basename(remotefile)`

```
getbinaryfile(remotefile, 
              localfile=File.basename(remotefile), 
              blocksize=DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
```

If you want `localfile` to be `nil` you have to pass it explicitly:

```
ftp.getbinaryfile(file, nil)
```

Comment: I have tried ftp.getbinaryfile(file, nil), and it seemed to return data now. thank you However, do you know why it would be so much slower?  When I save a file down to a file, the file is saved in less than a second.  If I used ftp.getbinaryfile(file,nil) it takes about 1 minute to return the data.

Comment: I've tried and I didn't experienced such a difference between writing to a file and just returning the string assigning the result to a variable, what do you do with the data returned?

Comment: right now, nothing, just displaying the data in the irb. The file is large, about 30mb. Seems that if I add, "; nil" to suppress output, it gets faster. thanks!

Comment: @user2012677 "Just displaying the data in irb" is what take all that time.